# how to set backgroundImage with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, getelementbyid, linear-gradients

```
function myFunction2() {
  for (let i=1; i < 3; i++){
    if (i<2){
      var numhex = (Math.random() * 0xfffff * 1000000).toString(16);
      var hex1 = '#' + numhex.slice(0, 6);
      // return hex1;
      // console.log(hex1);
    }
    else {
      var numhex = (Math.random() * 0xfffff * 1000000).toString(16);
      var hex2 = '#' + numhex.slice(0, 6);
      // return hex2;
      // console.log(hex2);
    }
    
  }
  // document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to right, " + {hex1} + ", " + {hex2} + ")";
  document.getElementById("container").setProperty("background-image", "linear-gradient(to right, " + {hex1} + ", " + {hex2});
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = "The code of the color is: linear-gradient( 270deg, " + hex1 + ", " + hex2 + " );";
};
```

> Hello, I am trying to set two colors for linear-gradient as parameters
> inside a specific element's background-image property, but it seems
> that something is wrong with my setProperty. Everything is working
> fine except this line of code.
> ***I've also tried it with style.backgroundImage with no result.***
> ***I am new to js.***
> ***Thanks in advance***

Comment: You've included code for `myFunction` but you're not calling it anywhere, and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Is commented line works properly?

Comment: -- Andy It is called my HTML file, but I didn't find it useful to write down the whole code here because the rest of it works properly.
--Quippe the last commented line with getElementById no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code . It worked

```
document.getElementById('container').style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, ${hex1} , ${hex2} )`;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, here is a tip: never use 'var', use 'let' instead.
There is no `setProperty()` function in JS, you need to use `element.style["style you want to change"] = "what you want to change it to"`.
And, you should not wrap the variables in '{}'s, or they become not variables, so the code should be:

```js
function myFunction2() {
  for (let i=1; i < 3; i++){
    if (i<2){
      var numhex = (Math.random() * 0xfffff * 1000000).toString(16);
      var hex1 = '#' + numhex.slice(0, 6);
      // return hex1;
      // console.log(hex1);
    }
    else {
      var numhex = (Math.random() * 0xfffff * 1000000).toString(16);
      var hex2 = '#' + numhex.slice(0, 6);
      // return hex2;
      // console.log(hex2);
    }
    
  }
  document.getElementById("container").style["background-image"] = "linear-gradient(to right, " + hex1 + ", " + hex2 + ")";
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = "The code of the color is: linear-gradient( 270deg, " + hex1 + ", " + hex2 + " );";
};
```

Also, if you are using a div, you have to define height too.

Comment: "_There is no setProperty() function in JS_" Right, but inline style object has the said method.

Comment: you are right I confused it with the setProperty() method of a CSS declaration block.